# Postgres: should one create indexes before or after populating tables

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am setting up a database which has hourly tables.  Each table is created in a single copy statement.  The purpose of the tables is to hold an indexed summary of the data held in standard files that compress really well.  For the record these files hold Internet flow data.

Sometimes we need to search over a months files looking for specific addresses and working through the files one at a time takes a long time so the intention is to build an index of each hour file which lists that IP Addresses for that hour.   To search we go serially through the time range we are interested in and do a quick search on each hour to see if we need to unpack and search the corresponding file on disk.

I am using Postgres since it supports IP addresses natively.  So for each hour I create a table with a name related to the corresponding file on disk (date and time, surprise).  I need indexes for the source and destination addresses but should I create those indexes before or after I load the data using a copy statement.

I guess another way of putting it is whether it is faster to do the indexing when the data is being loaded or in one go after it is all done.

Once a table is loaded it will normally never be modified until it is deleted.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your problem and I guess it might highly depend on the rows per table. Anyways, why do you need to make a huge bunch of different tables for this? I would recommend using only one table for all the data and add a foreign key to a second table that holds a reference to the file. Searching on these 2 tables seems by far easier than searching on many different tables with dynamic tablenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Postgres are you on?

Have you considered partitioning?

And, yes, it ought to be faster to build the index at the end, but that leaves out a lot of nuance.

Comment: I am using 10.something ( whatever ubuntu 18.04 installed).  No I did not know about partitioning and yes it looks very much like what I need - that is why I always try and give context in my posts.  Often I am asking the wrong question.  Understood about the nuance!  ;) .

Comment: Partitioning improves in PG 11 in ways that likely matter to you, if upgrading is an option. Regarding index building, Postgres has lots of tools for measuring the size of indexes, and you can time results in psql, or whatever client you use. For sizes, see pg_relation_size as a starting point, if you're concerned about size.