# postgres: Partitioned tables: split on unique values

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

background information in [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151333/postgres-should-one-create-indexes-before-or-after-populating-tables).

Postgres version 10.10

I need to partition a table on unique values of a column (varchar) which contains a file name but I can not figure out how do this.   LIST clearly does not work but I can't see how to specify a RANGE that will produce a partition for each unique value of the column.

Undoubtedly blindingly obvious when you see it!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might as well answer it since I have been searching for one myself.

I ended up using LIST partitioning myself with a single element in the LIST. It seems to give all the promised functionalities of the partitioned (and, in my case, sub-partitioned) tables.

However, Postgres doesn't seem to have algorithms inbuilt to use the indexes on the partition columns. Even while selecting distinct values on the partition column from the master table, Postgres does a seq scan on most of the level 1 and level 2 tables. That to me, is very silly since the partition LIST is known upfront, so all it had to do was get all the values from this LIST and do the seq scan on the default partition (if it existed)....

Answer (score -1):

List partitioning would be correct. If that doesn't seem feasible, you probably shouldn't partition the table by that column at all.

You shouldn't end up with thousands of partitions if you want good performance. If you cannot enumerate the file names, it seems like you have too many of them.

The first question you'll have to answer is if your queries or (most important) your `DELETE` statements will become faster by partitioning. If not, don't do it at all.